# Default form values defined right in *Type class

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I have such form definition class:

```
class HistorySliderType extends AbstractType
{

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('date', 'datetime', array(
            'date_widget' => 'single_text',
            'time_widget' => 'single_text',
            'date_format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
            'with_seconds' => true
        ));
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array(
            'data' => array('date' => new \DateTime())
        );
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    function getName()
    {
        return 'acme_tbundle_historyslidertype';
    }
}
```

and I expected the `date` field to be `now` as default, while the fields stay blank on form rendering.

Am I missing something or `getDefaultOptions` isn't supposed to be used to specify the initial (default) form values?

**UPD**:

After some research I came to the thoughts that it is a bug, so filled it: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/3288

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `data` option when adding the field:

```
$builder->add('token', 'hidden', array(
    'data' => 'abcdef',
));
```

Comment: `'data' => new \DateTime()` throws `Expected argument of type "DateTime", "array" given` :-S

Comment: That may indeed be a bug. My code came from symfony.com: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/field.html#data

Comment: yep... let's see what they will answer there